# How do I retrieve a textbox value using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the value of a textbox using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463506/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-textbox-using-jquery)

on form submit, i am trying to grab the value of the textbox below and shove it in an url

```
<input type="text" style="width: 300px" id="fromAddress" name="from" value="" />&nbsp;
```

here is my jquery code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     $(document).ready(function() {

         $(":submit").click(function(e) {

             var from = $("input#fromAddress").text;
             $('div#printdirec').html('<a target="_blank" href="http://maps.google.com/addr=' + from + '&daddr">Print Directions</a>');

         });

     });
</script>
```

when i look at the URL, it doesn't have the correct from address.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to use the `val()` function to get the textbox value. `text` does not exist as a property only as a function and even then its not the correct function to use in this situation.

```
var from = $("input#fromAddress").val()
```

`val()` is the standard function for getting the value of an input.

Answer (score 3):

Just Additional Info which took me long time to find.what if you were using the field name and not id for identifying the form field. You do it like this:

For radio button:

```
var inp= $('input:radio[name=PatientPreviouslyReceivedDrug]:checked').val();
```

For textbox:

```
var txt=$('input:text[name=DrugDurationLength]').val();
```