# Arrays in jquery-ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays

UPDATE:

Sorry I mean to say how may i use JS arrays with ajax?

Comment: Array in jQuery are the same as Javascript array..what's the difficult part you don't understand ? Have you read the official doc ?

Comment: You want to send a javascript array to the server using ajax? Where does the array come from?

Comment: Please clarify and improve your question to receive a good answer.

Comment: jQuery is a Javascript library. Arrays are a language feature of Javascript (well, kind of).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in javascript are very easy to use. To set up an array, simply set up the array like this.

```
var myArray = new Array(); 
myArray[0]="one value";      
myArray[1]="two value";
myArray[2]="three value"; //etc
```

You don't need AJAX to store data from a text box, as the DOM can grab the contents of a text box without any ajax calls.

In jQuery, you can get the contents of a text box like this `$("#idofyourtextbox").val();`

Reference: [How do I get the value of a textbox using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463506/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-textbox-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

What about `push`

```
var array = new Array();

array.push(value);
```