# Select dropbox value through php?

Tags: php, select, drop-down-menu, dropbox

I have this small problem with my PHP code, there is this website using a dropbox, and I want to show one of these values.
file_get_contents on the link where it is located, and now i need to select the dropbox.
Once this is done, there are like 400-500 options, and I want to select the value you typed in a textbox.
Could you guys help me started?
If you are wondering, my school website has our lesson shedules on their website in the dropbox, but i dont want to search for names every time, so when i type my name in the textbox, it needs to select it in the form, thanks alot!

Comment: I think that you might want to achieve what you are looking for using Javacript instead of PHP.

Comment: Allright, will try that, hope it works!
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with normal javascript, but I recommend getting used to jQuery, it's easier to learn and quicker to use IMHO:

http://jquery.com/

Get the value of the input box:

[How do I get the value of a textbox using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463506/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-textbox-using-jquery)

And then change the value of the select box:

[Change the selected value of a drop-down list with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499405/change-the-selected-value-of-a-drop-down-list-with-jquery)