# Getting textbox's value using jQuery

Tags: jquery, textbox

I am creating a login form dynamically, using jQuery and AJAX response. Form is created and displaying properly. But, I'm not able to read the form data.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#proper-form').on( 'click', '#submit-button', function() {  // loginForm is submitted

alert ("here");
    var username = $('#email').attr('value'); // get username
    var password = $('#password').attr('value'); // get password
alert (password);
alert (username);

    // code for form submit using ajax

 }); 
});
```

It's alerting `undefined undefined` for both username and password.

Can anyone help me in figuring out what's wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the value of a textbox using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463506/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-textbox-using-jquery)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just  use the [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val1) function, to get the value:

```
 var username = $('#email').val(); 
 var password = $('#password').val();
```

To set the value use [`val(value)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value) function:

```
$('#email').val('some new value');
```

Comment: Thanks for your very quick response. Working fine. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use .val() to read the value of an input element, not attribute

```
var username = $('#email').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already good answers here, but I thought you should understand why using .attr() doesn't work, even though value is indeed an attribute of the input field.

When you use 
        $('#email').attr('value');, 
this is equivalent to something like:

```
    input.getAttribute('value'),
```

which would return "something" for:

```
    <input type="text"value="something"/>
```

regardless of what the user typed in.

However, using 
        `$('#email').val()`
 is equivalent to something like:
`input.value` which would instead return whatever the user actually typed into the field.

In this case, you don't have a value="" implicitly set: you just want what the user typed in.

Therefore, use `.val()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){             
$("#test").click(function(){ 
//textbox            
        var first_name = $("#first_name").val();
        alert(first_name);
 });
 });
</script>
<div>username <input type="text" id="first_name" class="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="type username"/>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="test" class="shortc-button small blue">Get Data</a></div>
```

For more details visit : http://www.codingprogrammer.com/tutorialdemo/jquery-tutorial/get-value-of-textbox-in-jquery-example/