# how to get the value of textbox in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i want to get the value of textbox on the basis of its class and id. this what i have done but it is not working for me.
although i can set the value of textbox by doing this.Please help me out

```
<script>
....
var count=1;
var check=$(".AssVal,#"+count).val();
....
<script>
<input type="text" value="0" class="AssVal" id="1"  maxlength="20" size="20" />
```

This is how i set the value in textbox

```
var check=$(".AssVal,#"+count).val(123);
```

Comment: +1 for the ass class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the value of a textbox using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463506/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-textbox-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Since an ID attribute is **unique**, you can just use the ID on it's own:

```
// Get value
var check=$("#"+count).val();
// Set value
$("#"+count).val(123);
```

But the problem with your selector is that jQuery is trying to find all `.AssVal` elements **and** all elements with `id=1` as a comma in a selector denotes attempting to join [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

**use class selector . is used for selecting classes and # for ID**

```
var testvalue = $(".AssVal").val()
```

or

```
var testvalue = $("#1").val() // try not using no's as id
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can get the value simply by not passing any arguments to the `val()` function you've already used. This would look like:

`var myValue = $(".AssVal,#"+count).val();`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value using class as below

```
 $(".AssVal").val("123");
```

By ID as

```
$("#1").val("123");
```

For getting

```
alert($("#1").val());
alert($(".AssVal").val());
```

And for dynamic

```
alert($("#"+count).val());
```