# Linking checkbox's checked state to a value of a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql

Would like to know how to link a checkbox's checked state to a value on a textfield returned from an sql query.  The textbox value is updated after a user selects a value from a select/menu on the form. The value of the select menu option is used as a filter in the query, which is working fine.

```
if ($('#textbox').val("TRUE")
    { $('#mycheckbox').prop('checked',true);}
else
    {
     $('#mycheckbox').prop('checked',false);
   }
```

The problem is that the if statement works for the previous value the user selected.  So its always one click behind even though the textbox value is current.  Although the value of the textbox is current on the form, when I make an alert box displaying the textbox's value, it too is behind.  So the if statement is ok, its just its using the textbox's previous value and not the current one.  Any way to make this current?

Comment: Make sure that block of code is being executed after your AJAX call is successful.

Comment: Add the code block when you are updating the value of **textbox**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have syntax error in your code, assuming that is a typo.

What you are doing by`$('#textbox').val("TRUE")` is setting the value of **textbox** to **TRUE**.

So whenever your code block will execute you will end-up with checked check box, and textbox with **TRUE** value.

If your goal is to update the checkbox as per the value of text box. you can put the following one liner code instead of your four line, when you are actually setting/updating the value of text box.

> $('#mycheckbox').prop('checked',$('#textbox').val() == "TRUE")

**Update**

As you mentioned you are setting the new value after a ajax call and didn't included your code sample, I'm guessing, your code is something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "your/url"
}).done(function(data) {
  $('#textbox').val(data)
});
```

If so, update your code to

```
$.ajax({
  url: "your/url"
}).done(function(data) {
  $('#textbox').val(data);
  $('#mycheckbox').prop('checked',$('#textbox').val() == "TRUE");
});
```

The response is based on guess.

Comment: It still checks the box based on a value selected previously.  Its one user selection behind.

Comment: I asked where you are setting/updating the value for textbox?

Comment: @user3527363: And please clear one thing, **"Its one user selection behind"** your code doesn't contain the part of your selection mechanism!!

Comment: when a user selects a value on a select menu box the id is sent by ajax and is used as a filter on a query.  The query results are json parsed and the textbox value is set in this manner.  So the text boxes new value is the value pulled from the MySQL database.  If you want I can show you the code, but its working fine.

Comment: As i stated in my answer, Then you need to put the code when you are updating the value of textbox. In your case i guessing you have called `$('#textbox').val(newValue)` or something like that in your code. put my code after that.

Comment: YES, that did it.  Thank you so much, as you may have guessed I am a noob....   Works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statment is not testing the value of `#textbox` it is actually setting a value.

Try changing your `if` statement to read:

```
if ($('#textbox').val() == "TRUE")
```

Here's another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463506/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-textbox-using-jquery) that might help.

Comment: == did not work, it is still using the previous user selection, not the current one.