# Get the value of an id element in jquery

Tags: jquery

How in jQuery I can get the value of my  element (i.e.: 2).

I try with `$(this).("label").attr('for')`, but it does not work.

Thanks.

---

## My HTML is:

```
<div class="checkbox col-sms-6 col-sm-6 moods">
  <label for="2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="2">2
  </label>
</div>
```

## My js is:

```
$("form").on("click", "div.moods", function(event){
    var moodsId = $(this).("label").attr('for');
    var moodsBtn = $('#moods');
    var moodsBtnValue = $('#moods').val();

    if(moodsBtnValue.toString().indexOf(moodsId) == -1) { moodsBtn.val(moodsBtnValue + moodsId + ","); }
    else { moodsBtn.val(moodsBtnValue.replace(moodsId + ',','')); }
});
```

Comment: It would be better if you made a jsFiddle demo.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the value of a textbox using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463506/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-textbox-using-jquery)

Comment: @DavidThomas - it also doesn't have a HEAD/BODY/HTML tag -- he's just showing us a snippet.

Comment: So we assume, but since we're not seeing the relevant ('[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)') code, it's harder to offer definitive help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `.find` method to get a subelement:

```
var id = $(this).find("label").attr('for')
```

Then to get the value you would do:

```
$('#moods').find("#" + id).val();
```

Comment: A shortcut for using find is to dictate the `this` context, `$("label",this).attr("for")`

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
$(this).find(">:first-child").attr('for');
```

or

```
$(this).children(":first").attr('for');
```