# Add a new row to an HTML table when the previous/current is filled

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net, html-table

I'm short in time and will try to be brief, if there is a problem with my explanation I'll try to edit at night.

Simply, I have a table, Name and Age, it starts when the page loads with one row. When the first one is filled with something that is not null, automatically another row loads empty.

I prefer using JavaScript but I could also manage with asp.net.
I hope I explained myself well and sorry for being so brief.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: code

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="margin:10px" id="tablaSKU" runat="server">
                          <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>SKU</th>
                                <th>Precio €</th>
                                <th>Descripción</th>
                                <th>Fecha Inicio Demo</th>
                                <th>Fecha Fin Demo</th>
                                <th>Tipo de préstamo</th>
                              </tr>
                          </thead>
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <th>1-</th>
                                <th class="col-sm-2" name="sku"><asp:TextBox ID="sku" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox></th>
                                <th class="col-sm-1"><asp:TextBox ID="precio" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox></th>
                                <th class="col-sm-3"><asp:TextBox ID="descripProd" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox></th>
                                <th class="col-sm-2"><asp:TextBox ID="dataInit" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox></th>
                                <th class="col-sm-2"><asp:TextBox ID="dataFin" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox></th>
                                <th class="col-sm-2"> 
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="opcion" runat="server" CssClass="formularioChekLst form-control">
                                        <asp:ListItem>Opciones : </asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Opción 1</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Opción 2</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Opcion 3</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </th>
                              </tr>

                            </tbody>
                          </table>
```

HTML Code

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="margin:10px" id="tablaSKU" runat="server">
                      <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>SKU</th>
                            <th>Precio €</th>
                            <th>Descripción</th>
                            <th>Fecha Inicio Demo</th>
                            <th>Fecha Fin Demo</th>
                            <th>Tipo de préstamo</th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <th>1-</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-2"><input ID="sku" runat="server" class="form-control"></input></th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1"><input ID="precio" runat="server" class="form-control"></input></th>
                            <th class="col-sm-3"><input ID="descripProd" runat="server" class="form-control"></input></th>
                            <th class="col-sm-2"><input ID="dataInit" runat="server" class="form-control"></input></th>
                            <th class="col-sm-2"><input ID="dataFin" runat="server" class="form-control"></input></th>
                            <th class="col-sm-2"> 
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="opcion" runat="server" CssClass="formularioChekLst form-control">
                                    <asp:ListItem>Opciones : </asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Opción 1</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Opción 2</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Opcion 3</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </th>
                          </tr>


                        </tbody>
                      </table>
```

Comment: Without code, it will impossible to help you.

Comment: Have you looked at jquery? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463506/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-textbox-using-jquery) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619445/the-prefered-way-of-creating-a-new-element-with-jquery) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327047/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-create-html-elements-using-jquery) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481152/how-to-detect-a-textboxs-content-has-changed) even just [looking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery?rq=1) at the "related questions" on the right side.

Comment: Yes I did, but all are related to buttons. What I want is when the line is filled to create a new one

Answer (score 0):

With no examples, I've tried my best to cover what I think you mean, please see my examples below...

HMTL:

```
<form id=myform>
    <table id="mytable" data-row-prototype="&lt;tr&gt; &lt;td&gt;Name:&lt;/td&gt; &lt;td&gt;&lt;input type=&quot;text&quot; name=&quot;name[]&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt; &lt;tr&gt; &lt;td&gt;Age:&lt;/td&gt; &lt;td&gt;&lt;input type=&quot;number&quot; name=&quot;age[]&quot;&gt;&lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt;">
    </table>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
var table = $('#mytable');

function appendRow() {
  table.append(table.data('row-prototype'));
}

$(function() {
  appendRow(); // Append the first row on page load

  $('form#myform').on('change', function () {
    var inputs = $(this).find(':input'),
        valid = true;
    $.each(inputs, function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
        valid = false;
      }
    });

    if (valid) {
        appendRow();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Alright thanks for your first answer, the code is the following (using asp.net)

Comment: Ah sorry, I don't know ASP. I hope my answer can shed some light on an answer in ASP.

Comment: Regardless your answer didn't work in jsfiddle... Damn struggling

Comment: Hi, you'd need to include the jquery library for it to work, see my jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/cpvb492m/

Comment: You were right it worked, the only thing I don't understand is the data-raw-prototype structure of the command, what is evertyhing you wrote in there. If you can explain it I will give another try.

Comment: The prototype is basically the table template, its a html encoded string of "<tr><td><input></td></tr>, this allows the developer to supply a "template" for the table & then jquery will simply append the html into the table when required.

Comment: I'm no ASP developer, so dont quote me on this, but you could do something like Server.HTMLEncode('<tr><td>...</td></tr>') to make the template more readable.

Comment: I will look into it, but just tried to use your code on my current project posted previously and its not working, I don't know why. I edited now with the table on html

Comment: Please make sure you include "<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>" in your web page.

Comment: Already had those    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>                                                                          No error returned by chrome console, simply doesnt work. Maybe because of the data-row-prototype? If you have time see the last HTML code I posted, please.

Comment: As previously mentioned, I'm not an ASP developer so I've converted the asp inputs to plain html, please see my updated jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/qf6mxkwa/

Comment: Hello and once again thanks for your help.                                           
I looked for an online HTML encoder and generated the code.
Also, by using windows.alerts I see that it enters the first function AppendRow and executes.
It also detects when an input is changed inside the form (tested with window alert)
And it also executes the if (valid), but it doesn' seem to add the row.
Feels like Im getting close thanks for your help.

Comment: If there's any errors, they should appear in your console log

Comment: And today the exact same code is giving me this error
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
http://localhost:50480/FormDemo/css/cookies.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)' refering to this line
        var content = table.data('row-prototype').replace(/__id__/g, rowCount);

Comment: That would happen if the ID of the table has been changed, or the data-prototype-row doesn't exist in the table. Please make sure ASP is outputting the table exactly as is in the js fiddle.

Comment: Hello I created a window.alert(table) which returns [object Object].
When I try to log window.alert(table.data('row-prototype')) returns as udnefined. 
I legit copied the same code from <table> to </table> of the js fiddle and still returns unedefined when trying to see table.data('row-prototype').


Thank you

Comment: UPDATE : Managed to get the first part to work moving the <script> to the bottom of the page, still, it will just draw the first line and not create new ones when the first one is completed.

Comment: UPDATE : Changed de form id =myform to < div > tag because ASP internal problems and its working now, thank you so much LMS94