# Cant get input text value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the text of the input text field on click of the go button. I have read a few tutorials on this, followed them step by step, but still failed to do so. Here is my code :

```js
function go() {
  content.html($("#textfield").value);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <input type="text" id="textfield">
    <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="go()">Go</button>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

May I ask what is wrong with it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463506/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-textbox-using-jquery

Comment: use .val() instead of .value

Comment: function go()
        {
            $("#content").html($("#textfield").val());
        }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `.val()` to get value of input.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="content">
  <input type="text" id="textfield">
  <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="go()">Go</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function go()
{
    console.log($("#textfield").val());
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things: even though `content` should be a global reference to `<div id="content">`, you should not rely on this mechanism. That DOM reference won't have jQuery's HTML method anyway; instead, you should look the DOM node up using `$('#content')` or something similar. Additionally, jQuery provides a `val()` method to get an input value, `.value` is the native DOM API:

```
$('#content').html($("#textfield").val())
```